# Thump in transmission when braking

Tags: noise, automatic-transmission, chrysler, chrysler-300c

Transmission on 2014 Chrysler 300 AWD make a thump noise in the transmission when applying brake. Mechanic listening to noise with a stethoscope to confine noise. Transmission is starting to slip slightly with only 53000 miles. Car was up on rack and I heard the thump coming from transmission when hitting brakes. Seems to shift ok when driving but seems like it’s not normal

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

This could be a mechanical issue, but it could also be the adaptations need to be reset. Many modern cars' computers are designed to learn your driving style and adapt throttle response and gear changes accordingly. This can occasionally lead to some off behavior, for instance thumping, for example my Mercedes started thumping into lower gear when I was slowing down under medium braking.

The nice thing is that resetting your adaptations are free, you can disconnect the negative battery terminal for 10 minutes, or pull the PCM and transmission control fuses for 10 minutes before reinserting them. Either will clear the adaptations from the computers.

This may not be your problem, but it's extremely easy to eliminate as a possibility.